# Notification Popup in WPF

Tags: wpf

The question sounds duplicate, but believe me I have checked other answers, but did not find answer.

In my WPF application with MVVM, I have a `MessageNotificationView` (view). Whenever there is any error, this view gets pop-ed up. Everything works fine, the only issue is, the User have to interact with the main window.

For instance, if a hardware is disconnected from the system, this pop up should come **immediately and automatically**. The "Immediate" part is working, but "Automatic" part is not working. I need to click anywhere in the window, then only the popup comes.

Any suggestion?

Comment: so, if you're application isn't focused, it won't fire the notification?

Comment: @Noctis That is optional requirement. But now even though the application is focused, the pop up comes when I click somewhere, does not come automatically.

Comment: what do you mean "when you click somewhere" ? why do you need to click? how did you wire up the binding, and who fires the event / message?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a trigger , when having any Notification then visible true else false.

below is example, i am using for show error, when having any error in application will visible else collapsed.

```
<Style x:Key="PanelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsException}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsException}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

hope this will help.